# ace tao client multiple certificates

Tags: c++, ssl-certificate, corba, ace, tao

I'm trying to write a multithreaded client with the ACE+TAO framework which connects to multiple CORBA-Servers simultaneously. Each Server exposes the same CORBA-Interface but has a different set of SSL-Keys.

So each client has to use different SSL-Keys to be able to connect to the server.

I've got multiple client configs:

```
dynamic SSLIOP_Factory Service_Object * TAO_SSLIOP:_make_TAO_SSLIOP_Protocol_Factory() "-SSLAuthenticate SERVER_AND_CLIENT -SSLPrivateKey 'PEM:client3-key.pem' -SSLCertificate 'PEM:client3-client-cert.pem' -SSLCAFile 'PEM:client3-cacert.pem'"
dynamic Advanced_Resource_Factory Service_Object* TAO_Strategies:_make_TAO_Advanced_Resource_Factory() "-ORBProtocolFactory SSLIOP_Factory"
static Client_Strategy_Factory "-ORBConnectStrategy blocked"
```

When I initialize the first ORB then I can see that the SSLIOP Protocol is loaded and the keys for the first client are also loaded. The connection to the first server then works as intended.

But when I try to initialize a connection to the second Server (which uses different SSL-Keys) I can see that when the new ORB is initialized the SSLIOP Protocol is not initialized and still uses the SSL-Keys from the first server. As a consequence the connection to the second server fails.

```
CORBA::Object_var object = m_orb->string_to_object(m_ior_file.c_str());
```

fails with CORBA::TRANSIENT because the Keys do not match the server.

I tried passing "-ORBGestalt" "Local" and "-ORBCollocation" "no" to CORBA::ORB_init(), but without any success still the SSLIOP Protocol is only being configured the first time.

Is there any way to specify different SSL-Keys for different IORs or to reconfigure the SSLIOP Protocol?